# Is Subsonic compatible with .Net 4.0

Tags: subsonic

Is the latest version of Subsonic compatible with Visual Studio 2010 / .Net 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had version 3 working in the beta version of Visual Studio 2010 and .net 4 for a while now. It works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Subsonic 3 should work fine in .NET 4. I am developing a solution on VS.NET 2010 using Subsonic 3 and so far no problems at all.

Answer (score 2):

Subsonic is just a 3.5 library.... whether you have .net 4.0 or .net X.X in the future it should still compile to 3.5... just as a .Net 2.0 project will still load.

Short answer yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the latest release version is a .NET 3.5 library that will work with .NET 4.0.  I would assume the source would compile under .NET 4.0 but have not tried that myself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't noticed any problems referencing 3.0.0.3 in a .NET 4.0 project.