# Subsonic and .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, orm, subsonic, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Subsonic compatible with .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425608/is-subsonic-compatible-with-net-4-0)

Does Subsonic support .Net 4.0?